# How to close the form on mouse click?

Tags: powershell, mouseevent

I'm creating a Graphical Date Picker in PowerShell, based on this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730942.aspx). The following part of the code in the article helps to close the form after the date selection and pressing Enter key:

```
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
        {
            $dtmDate=$objCalendar.SelectionStart
            $objForm.Close()
        }
    })
```

I also want to add mouse event for the date selection and to close the form. So the question is, how do we close the form once the date has been selected and on MouseUp event?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of registering an event handler for all `Click`/`MouseDown`/`MouseUp` events, you could use the [DateSelected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.dateselected(v=vs.110).aspx) event instead. From the description:

> Occurs when the user makes an explicit date selection using the mouse.

```
$objForm.Add_DateSelected({
        $dtmDate=$objCalendar.SelectionStart
        $objForm.Close()
    })
```

In PowerShell 3.0 or newer, you may have to change the scope of `$dtmDate` variable in order for it to work:

```
$script:dtmDate = $objCalendar.SelectionStart
```

or (`-Scope 1` means "direct parent scope" or "1 step up the call stack")

```
Set-Variable -Scope 1 -Name dtmDate -Value $objCalendar.SelectionStart
```